# Trying to pass an Image Data to another screen in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm building an App that requires the capturing of an Image and display in another screen.

**DeviceproblemScreen.js** (*This is where I am capturing the image from*)

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Brokenglasspro', {
imageData: '<../assets/images/screendamage.png>'})} 

style={styles.button}>.............
```

**DisplayScreen.js**(*This is where i want the image to display*)
....................

```
 <Image style={{ width.........}}
    source={route.params.imageData={uri:"../assets/images/screendamage.png;"+{imageData}}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the following way:

From your `DeviceproblemScreen.js` component, pass your image like so:

```
<TouchableOpacity
   onPress={() => 
     navigation.navigate('Brokenglasspro', {
       imageData: require('../assets/images/screendamage.png'})
     }
   }
   style={styles.button}
>.............
```

Then, in `DisplayScreen.js`,

```
<Image
   style={{ width.........}}
   source={navigation.getParam("imageData")}
/>
```

Just make sure `DisplayScreen.js` has access to `navigation`, and it should work for you (I just tested it to make sure :)).

Comment: Thanks @FredAstaire, Multiple screens navigate to the Display screen. As shown for one of the screen------> 
     <Button title="GET FREE ESTIMATE" onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Display', { paramkey1: name, paramkey2:email......................}); }} containerStyle={styles.button}.............................However when I write my code like you suggested i get a TypeError: navigation.getParam is not a function

Comment: Are you passing `navigation` as props, as in:
`const DisplayScreen = ({ navigation }) => {`

Comment: Yes I am -----> const DisplayScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {